# Running gp in sage how do I access. e.g.. e.j

Tags: sagemath

I am new to sage and I am trying to run the gp interface.

In gp I can define an elliptic curve e and then access j by e.j

```
? e=ellinit([0,-1,1,0,0]);
? e.j
%2 = -4096/11
```

Trying to do the same in sage I did

```
e=gp.ellinit([0,-1,1,0,0])
```

What is the syntax to return j for this e.  e.j does not work nor do variations like gp.e.j that I tried -- I know that j is stored in

```
e[13]
```

but I would like to use the syntax (or something close to) e.j, or e.disc, etc that I am used to typing when working directly in gp.

I am probably missing something very simple here. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://www.sagemath.org/doc/constructions/elliptic_curves.html

Comment: No - I want to access the j that is a member of e i.e e.j -- I don't want to calculate an new E in sage access member E.j_invariant().

Comment: @Amzoti I should added that it is not really j that I am interested in. That was just a reproducible example. I want to learn how to use the gp interface in sage to access the member x (i.e. X.x) for an object X in gp.